# How to return a promise value using Google Datastore?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, return, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently discovering Google Datastore and it seems pretty useful.

However (I'm a JS newbie) I'm stuck with something pretty simple concerning `Promise` and `Async/await`, and I'm not able to find my answer (I tried...).

This `get` works perfectly into my terminal (it's fairly simple):

```
datastore.get(datastore.key(['viewing', 'abc123']))
.then((slot) => {
  console.log(slot[0])
})
```

But what I want is to wrap this query into a `const` and return `slot[0]` on-demand...

So I've tried:

```
const wrap = () => {
  datastore.get(datastore.key(['viewing', 'abc123']))
    .then((slot) => {
      return slot[0]
    })
}
```

Didn't work. 
I've tried to add a `return` before `datastore.get`, to change a `return` for a `Promise.resolve`... but it's still the same : `Promise pending` (best case).

I do not speak about using `async/await`.
I can't `return` my `slot[0]`...

Any clue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you are dealing with is a promise. The way I always think about it is once you enter "Promise-Land" you can't escape. Some may see that as a bad thing but i think it's great.

Once you run the `get`, at some point in the future it will finish. When it does it calls the function inside the `then` and passes it the value. From this point on you have to work inside of `then` statements. (caveat below)

You can keep a reference to the promise and use it as a value

```
const omg = datastore.get(datastore.key(['viewing', 'abc123']))
```

You can only get at the value by using the `.then` function.

```
omg.then(console.log)
```

You can take your value and pass it to another function, whether a lambda:

```
omg
    .then(slot => slot[0])
    .then(console.log)
```

or a named function

```
const head = list => list[0];
omg
    .then(head)
    .then(console.log)
```

Thats the best way to use promises

If that is too foreign or you aren't used to that type of programming (functional) then you can use the imperative Async/Await.

```
const omg = await datastore.get(datastore.key(['viewing', 'abc123']))
```

It should do what you expect but has to be transpiled by babel or similar.